# Correlation with missing data

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists, age and score, that I want to find correlation on for 50 people. For some people, the score is blank.

Example data:

```
age={60., 21., 24., 63., 66., 62., 56., 54., 62.,...}
score={720., 880., 980., 820., , 820., 970., 950., 170.,...}
```

If I simply use DeleteCases to remove the " " from the score list, I change the length and cannot correlate the two lists of different lengths.

Suggestions?

Comment: I think you can only compare those which has both data so: `Pick[age, NumericQ/@score]` and then compare with `score/.""->Sequence[]`, or `DeleteCases` like with your approach.

Answer (score 6):

First, let's generate some sample data.  In your list you actually have an implicit [`Null`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Null.html) rather than the string `" "` which you also mention.  I'll use `Null` in mine, but the method should be the same whichever it is: `Null`, `" "`, `""`, etc.

```
age = 1 / Range[10];
score = 10 / age;
score[[{2, 6, 7, 10}]] = Null;
```

You can pair and filter the lists as [Anon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/anon) showed.  I would use `Cases` or `DeleteCases` myself, rather than `Sequence[]`:

```
DeleteCases[{age, score}\[Transpose], {_, }]
```

> ```
> {{1, 10}, {1/3, 30}, {1/4, 40}, {1/5, 50}, {1/8, 80}, {1/9, 90}}
> ```

```
Cases[{age, score}\[Transpose], {_, _?NumberQ}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 10}, {1/3, 30}, {1/4, 40}, {1/5, 50}, {1/8, 80}, {1/9, 90}}
> ```

[Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) recommended `Pick` and `DeleteCases` in a comment:

```
Pick[age, NumericQ /@ score]
DeleteCases[score, Null]
```

> ```
> {1, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/8, 1/9}
>
> {10, 30, 40, 50, 80, 90}
> ```

You could also make use of `Position`:

```
pos = Position[score, _?NumberQ];
Extract[#, pos] & /@ {age, score}
```

> ```
> {{1, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/8, 1/9}, {10, 30, 40, 50, 80, 90}}
> ```

A different method using `Pick`:

```
Pick[{age, score}, {#, #}] &[NumericQ /@ score]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/8, 1/9}, {10, 30, 40, 50, 80, 90}}
> ```

#### Performance

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

age = 1/Range[100000];
score = 10/age;
score[[ RandomSample[Range@100000, 10000] ]] = Null;

Transpose[{age, score}] /. {__, } -> Sequence[]                       // timeAvg
Cases[{age, score}\[Transpose], {_, _?NumberQ}]                       // timeAvg
DeleteCases[{age, score}\[Transpose], {_, }]                          // timeAvg
(pos = Position[score, _?NumberQ]; Extract[#, pos] & /@ {age, score}) // timeAvg
{Pick[age, NumericQ /@ score], DeleteCases[score, Null]}              // timeAvg
Pick[{age, score}, {#, #}] &[NumericQ /@ score]                       // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.03432
>
> 0.04244
>
> 0.02684
>
> 0.05616
>
> 0.01872
>
> 0.01872
> ```

`Pick` appears to be the fastest on this data; `DeleteCases` comes in second place.

Answer (score 4):

One way to get rid of the missing elements and the corresponding values from the score list would be this:

```
tmp=Transpose[{age, score}] /. {__, " "} -> Sequence[]
```

Then to update `age` and `score` you could do this:

```
{age, score} = Transpose[tmp]
```