# Delete Missing data from coordinate sets

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of pairs of coordinates, where some are missing.

```
coordinates = {
  {{1, 1}, {1, 2}},
  {{3, 4}, {5, 5}},
  {{1, 2}, Missing[]},
  {{9, 8}, {7, 7}},
  {Missing[], {2, 3}}
}
```

I am trying to remove the pairs containing missing coordinates, to get

```
coordinates = {
  {{1, 1}, {1, 2}},
  {{3, 4}, {5, 5}},
  {{9, 8}, {7, 7}},
}
```

I tried

```
coordinates = DeleteCases[coordinates, MemberQ[#, _Missing] &]
```

but that did not work. But the function `MemberQ` works on pairs directly:

```
MemberQ[coordinates[[1]], _Missing] (* returns False *)
MemberQ[coordinates[[3]], _Missing] (* returns True *)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `DeleteCases[coordinates, _?(MemberQ[#, _Missing] &)]` or `DeleteCases[coordinates, x_ /; MemberQ[x, _Missing]]` work

Comment: Related: [(1234)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1234), [(2655)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2655),
[(29159)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29159)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
coordinates = {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {5, 5}}, {{1, 2}, Missing[]}, {{9, 8}, {7, 7}}, {Missing[], {2, 3}}};
```

The second argument to `DeleteCases` must be a pattern not a boolean.

```
correctedCoordinates = DeleteCases[coordinates, _?(MemberQ[#, _Missing] &)]
```

> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {5, 5}}, {{9, 8}, {7, 7}}}

Similarly with `Cases`

```
correctedCoordinates == Cases[coordinates, _?(FreeQ[#, _Missing] &)]
```

> True

Whereas, `Select` requires a boolean.

```
correctedCoordinates == Select[coordinates, FreeQ[#, _Missing] &]
```

> True

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I was mistaken about what was going wrong.  Do you know what happened to MathGroup?  No new messages since May 22.

Comment: Presumably, most/all of the traffic migrated here and the moderator fell asleep. :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
DeleteCases[coordinates, {___, Missing[], ___}]
```

Or (slower)

```
Cases[coordinates, {{__?NumberQ}, {__?NumberQ}}]
```

I like this style because of its flexibility in more complicated cases.

With

```
x = Join @@ Table[coordinates, {10^5}];
```

Eldo `DeleteCases`       : 0.22 sec.
Szabolcs:                : 0.86 sec.
Bob Hanlon `DeleteCases` : 0.95 sec.

Answer (score 4):

Bob Hanlon has the answer, but merely as a supplement: if your data is as you show I would simply use [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Select.html) and [`MatrixQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixQ.html).

```
Select[coordinates, MatrixQ]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {5, 5}}, {{9, 8}, {7, 7}}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`DeleteMissing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteMissing.html?q=DeleteMissing):

```
DeleteMissing[coordinates, 1, 1]
```

> `{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {5, 5}}, {{9, 8}, {7, 7}}}`

but it's more than 4 times slower on my PC than the solution provided in [the answer by Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/49314/18476).